# Integrating Selenium and Scrapy to click past page and then save cookies

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, web-scraping, scrapy

I've been searching on stackoverflow for a couple hours now and still haven't been able to find a suitable answer for what I am currently doing. I want to use Selenium to get past an initial page to click through and then transfer the cookies to Scrapy to then crawl the database. So far I keep on getting redirected to the initial login page.

I based off grabbing the cookies and putting them in the request off of this answer 
[scrapy authentication login with cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200926/scrapy-authentication-login-with-cookies?rq=1)

```
class HooversTest(scrapy.Spider):
    global starturls
    name = "hooversTest"
    allowed_domains = ["http://subscriber.hoovers.com"]
    login_page = ["http://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/home/index.html"]
    start_urls = ["http://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/company360/overview.html?companyId=99566395", 
              "http://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/company360/overview.html?companyId=10723000000000"]



def login(self, response):
    return Request(url=self.login_page,
        cookies=self.get_cookies(), callback=self.after_login)

def get_cookies(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.get("http://www.mergentonline.com/Hoovers/continue.php?status=sucess")
    elem = self.driver.find_element_by_name("Continue")
    elem.click()
    time.sleep(15)
    cookies = self.driver.get_cookies()
    #reduce(lambda r, d: r.update(d) or r, cookies, {})
    self.driver.close()
    return cookies

def parse(self, response):
    return Request(url="http://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/company360/overview.html?companyId=99566395",
        cookies=self.get_cookies(), callback=self.after_login)


def after_login(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    print hxs.select('//title').extract()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on how it has "not worked"?