# Python scrapy reddit confirm button breaks crawl

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to crawl websites for data and when I get to a page for 18+, I get a warning page.  My crawler normally works on most reddit pages and I can get the data successfully.  I tried using selenium to move onto the next page, which when it opens the browser is successful, but the crawler doesnt follow to that page.  Below is my code..

```
class DarknetmarketsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "darknetmarkets"
    allowed_domains = ["https://www.reddit.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.reddit.com/r/darknetmarkets',
    )
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_obj', follow=False),)
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get('http://www.reddit.com/r/darknetmarkets')
        #self.driver.get('https://www.reddit.com/over18?dest=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Fdarknetmarketsnoobs')

        while True:
            try:
                YES_BUTTON = '//button[@value="yes"]'
                next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(YES_BUTTON).click()


                url = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/darknetmarkets'

                next.click()
            except:
                break

        self.driver.close()


        item = darknetItem()
        item['url'] = []
        for link in LinkExtractor(allow=(), deny=self.allowed_domains).extract_links(response):
            item['url'].append(link.url)
            print link
```

The css of the button..

```
<button class="c-btn c-btn-primary" type="submit" name="over18" value="yes">continue</button>
```

Comment: Reddit has [an API](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api).

Comment: I see mostly praw used, but prefer scrappy ..

Comment: Selenium and scrapy don't communicate with each other unless you specifically send from one to another. Once selenium crawls all websites, all the data is lost

Comment: Ahh interesting, is it possible to tackle this problem in scrapy then I guess is my question.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are trying to bypass the age restriction screen in that subreddit. After you click on the button "continue" that choice is saved as a cookie so you have to retrive into scrapy.

After you click on it with Selenium save the cookies and send them to scrapy

Code courtesy of [scrapy authentication login with cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200926/scrapy-authentication-login-with-cookies)

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'MySpider'
start_urls = ['http://reddit.com/']

def get_cookies(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    base_url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/darknetmarkets/"
    self.driver.get(base_url)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@value='yes']").click()
    cookies = self.driver.get_cookies()
    self.driver.close()
    return cookies

def parse(self, response):
    yield scrapy.Request("http://www.reddit.com/r/darknetmarkets/",
        cookies=self.get_cookies(),
        callback=self.darkNetPage)
```